# Using custom Machinepack in treeline.io

Tags: node.js, sails.js, treeline

I'm currently testing the beta of treeline.io, firstly it's awesome.

Secondly, i'm struggling with how i would add a custom Machinepack. I have one i need that's very specific to an application i'm testing that it doesn't make sense to add to NPM/Github.

Now if this was a sails app i could manually add it to api/machines, but that get's overwritten locally whenever i restart my treeline.io application.

Now i have the option of creating a new machine directly on treeline.io, but i can't then sync that locally to edit it, or actually get at the underlying code of the machinePack (i know that's kinda the point, but i am still always going to need to do some custom things).

Perfectly possible this just isn't quite there yet given the beta nature of things, just wanted to check i wasn't missing something!

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: What kind of custom things are you thinking you'd need to do outside of Treeline?

Comment: I needed to fetch a specific search term from Twitter and return it into treeline.io as new objects. I almost have it working by creating a new code machine, just trying to work out the parsing of the returned objects and i'm there. Loving treeline so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Treeline creates Sails.js apps for you, the goal is for you to never have to touch that generated code.  Anything you need to do, you should be able to do in Treeline using either an existing machine or one you create yourself.

If the specific functionality you need doesn't exist in the Twitter pack, a good practice is to create a custom *circuit* using a combination of the [sendHttpRequest](https://treeline.io/admin/machines/6eed9a6c-51c4-46d6-a85b-eafa0ceef03e) machine from the [HTTP pack](https://treeline.io/admin#/machinepacks/459ab538-3c6a-4a0d-ad61-895bd6097c06), and the [Parse JSON](https://treeline.io/admin/machines/97533f95-9bd5-4e82-949f-22b458a2be1d) machine from the [Util pack](https://treeline.io/admin#/machinepacks/0ccd2b47-a58e-4f8c-a3fd-d5a4ec77bfd5).  Ultimately we'll introduce a system where you can then contribute that machine back to the Twitter pack from within Treeline (like doing a pull request on Github).

At the very least, you should always be able to create a new *function* machine that contains Javascript code to do what you want.  Function machines can use dependencies from NPM.

If you create a new top-level Machinepack within Treeline, it will be installable by anyone else in the system (at least until private projects/packs are introduced).  If you think your custom machines are specific enough to not be useful to others, you can add them directly to your app instead.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is what i have done in the end, i have created a new function machine with the code i need. I could almost get it to work with a circuit, but there was no way to hash the data i needed for the OAuth to work with twitter. That said, i should probably have created a machine to do that hash function and kept everything else as standard machines. Oh well live and learn! FYI, entering of custom code is currently a little tedious, especially when it comes to things like entering Schemas for JSON validation e.t.c, would be really good to be able to paste/import these, less typos